# Remove span using VBScript regex

Tags: regex, vbscript

How do I remove a span tag using a VBScript regex? For example, the following HTML should be reduced to just the `h3` opening tag:

```
<h3><span style="color: inherit; font-size: 24px; line-height: 1.1;">
```

It must be by regex, as it is part of a regex process to standardize text. The content of the `span` can vary totally, and most of the time there is no `span`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the pattern `<span [^>]*>` to match the opening tag (`<span`) and then grab everything up to the closing `>`.

```
Dim s
s = "<h3><span style=""color: inherit; font-size: 24px; line-height: 1.1;"">"

With New RegExp
    .Pattern = "<span [^>]*>"
    s = .Replace(s, "")
End With
```

Comment: That worked, thanks indeed! I had to add the tag h3 before in the pattern to avoid all the span tags from being stripped out in the rest of the document. Sorry it seems I can't click to give one.